# Unable to play live streaming on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, gstreamer, h.264

Unable to play live stream on chrome.

I have created small html file in which i am passing tcp or http url of live streaming in video tag of html but it doesn't work. please find the screenshot of codec information in screenshot below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
<h1>
Testing H264 on chrome html5
</h1>
<video width="800" controls>
  <source src="tcp://[2612:f777:f:240e::898]:55151" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</body> 
</html>
```

profile set is baseline and i have tried replacing tcp with http but it doesn't work
expected : live stream should play on chrome
actual : black player screen only 
[Codec info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxx2d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chrome does not support `tcp://` as a protocol. In fact it does not support any live "streaming" protocol. You need to use a player like `video.js` or `hls.js` (which uses MSE) along with a proper format like `DASH` or `HLS`

Comment: Thanks for the input. But can we play h264 mpeg4 recorded video on chrome inside video tag?

Comment: Yes, but only when packaged and delivered correctly.

Comment: Thanks. So is it possible to play .h264 live streaming with any other browser ?

Comment: Its possible to play h264 on every browser. It not possible to use tcp:// on any browser.

Comment: so what will i pass in video tag of html ? any other transport protocol ?

Comment: For live? No transport will work. You must manually get the fragments via XHR/fetch/web socket or webrtc data channel, and add the bytes to MSE via a blob. Or you can use a player that will do that for you like I suggested in the answer.

Comment: For .h264 live streaming no transport will work on any browser. is that correct  ?

Comment: The codec and the transport are unrelated. Your codec is fine. Your transport is bad.